# File access from a background task in a windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-async

I can't seem to read a file from a background task in a windows store app. Here's the code that reads the file content:

```
async private static Task<string> ReadAsync(string FileName)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    string content = string.Empty;
    using (Stream stream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            try
            {
                // *** program exits on this line
                content = await Task.Run(() => reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // no error is caught
                content = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```

The program **exits** on the line that calls ReadToEnd() on the StreamReader - no error is caught in the try catch block. In the output window I get:

The program '[8968] backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1 (0x1)

**Is it possible to access files a background task? If so, where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Wire up these exception handler's and tell us if it provides any more info to aid troubleshooting: 
`Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ApplicationThreadException);` and 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ApplicationUnhandledException);`

Comment: I'm not sure if these handlers are available in WinRT? I've tried adding these to App.xaml.cs but the compiler doesn't recognize them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted your `IBackgroundTask` code. Without seeing it I suspect you didn't call `GetDeferral()` inside it, e.g.:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    var contents = await ReadAsync("MyFile.txt");
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

You need to call `GetDeferral()` whenever you are making asynchronous calls inside your background task. This way you tell the runtime it needs to wait for the asynchronous call to complete and not stop the background task as soon as `Run` exits.

Once you're done, i.e. usually at the end of your `Run` method, you need to call `Complete()` on the deferral instance to notify the runtime that you're done.

Comment: Spot on! I wasn't using a deferral in my IBackgroundTask

Answer (score -1):

There are already system classes (DataReader) to read file asynchronously, so I'm not sure why you decided to write your own.